# Command not found in Raspbian /etc/profile script

Tags: linux, bash, debian, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I have modified my `/etc/profile` script at the end to automatically load `rvmsudo siriproxy server`, however I get some strange errors:

**/etc/profile**

```
# /etc/profile: system-wide .profile file for the Bourne shell (sh(1))
# and Bourne compatible shells (bash(1), ksh(1), ash(1), ...).

if [ "`id -u`" -eq 0 ]; then
  PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/home/pi/.rvm/bin:/home/pi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@SiriProxy/bin"
else
  PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games:/home/pi/.rvm/bin:/home/pi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@SiriProxy/bin"
fi
export PATH

if [ "$PS1" ]; then
  if [ "$BASH" ] && [ "$BASH" != "/bin/sh" ]; then
    # The file bash.bashrc already sets the default PS1.
    # PS1='\h:\w\$ '
    if [ -f /etc/bash.bashrc ]; then
      . /etc/bash.bashrc
    fi
  else
    if [ "`id -u`" -eq 0 ]; then
      PS1='# '
    else
      PS1='$ '
    fi
  fi
fi

# The default umask is now handled by pam_umask.
# See pam_umask(8) and /etc/login.defs.

if [ -d /etc/profile.d ]; then
  for i in /etc/profile.d/*.sh; do
    if [ -r $i ]; then
      . $i
    fi
  done
  unset i
fi

alias ls='ls --color'
cd ~/SiriProxy
rvmsudo siriproxy server
```

The first two lines work where I'm setting the `ls` color alias and the directory change. The problem is the following:

```
Last login: Fri Sep 28 11:42:44 2012 from 192.168.10.94
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': cannot load such file -- bundler (LoadError)
        from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
        from /home/pi/SiriProxy/lib/siriproxy/command_line.rb:177:in `load_code'
        from /home/pi/SiriProxy/lib/siriproxy/command_line.rb:84:in `run_server'
        from /home/pi/SiriProxy/lib/siriproxy/command_line.rb:37:in `initialize'
        from bin/siriproxy:6:in `new'
        from bin/siriproxy:6:in `<main>'
pi@raspberrypi:~/SiriProxy$
```

What it's meant to do is the following:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/SiriProxy$ rvmsudo siriproxy server
Starting SiriProxy on port 443..
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Do `which rvmsudo`
2. Modify /etc/profile to do one of:

   - specify the absolute path to rvmsudo
   - include the directory rvmsudo is in on the path.

Comment: `which rvmsudo` revealed: `/home/pi/.rvm/bin/rvmsudo` so I changed it to: `/home/pi/.rvm/bin/rvmsudo siriproxy server` and I get: `/usr/bin/env: siriproxy: No such file or directory` now. I also added the bin directory to the `PATH`. NOTE: The command `rvmsudo siriproxy server` needs to be run within `~/SiriProxy`.

Comment: The message above sounds like rvmsudo telling you that it can't find the siriproxy command, so you need to `which siriproxy` and apply the same fix (absolute path or add to path)

Comment: you need to look at your environment where siriproxy works - could be paths or env. vars. Could be the working dir.

Comment: Does bashrc mess with the path (and remove the stuff you just added)?